# How to sort a list of strings based on Character Frequency

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of strings, and i need to sort them based on the Frequency of A's in each word. If the A's are equal then compare the B's, and so on until Z. Assume there are no anagrams in the list ofcourse.

Example: `[Banana, Isle, Best, Barb]`

Sorted:     `[Banana, Barb, Best, Isle]`

Comment: turn each word into a char array, loop through the array and add 1 to a counter for each 'a' that appears in the array. Probably not the most efficient way though.

Answer (score 1):

The words in the initial array can be sorted using comparator for the converted string built from the sorted character array of the given word:

```java
public static String convert(String s) {
    char[] c = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(c);
    return new String(c);
}
```

```java
String[] data = {"Banana", "Isle", "Best", "Barb", "Abracadabra", "aardvark", "Barnabie"};
Arrays.sort(data, Comparator.comparing(MyClass::convert));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

Output:

```
[Abracadabra, Banana, aardvark, Barnabie, Barb, Best, Isle]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting on multiple criterias, 26 criterias, that will look like

```
# for banana, occurence of each char in alphabet
[3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So build that

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def sorter(word: str):
    word_low = word.lower()
    return [word_low.count(c) for c in ascii_lowercase]

values = ["Banana", "Isle", "Best", "Barb"]
values = sorted(values, key=sorter, reverse=True)
print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this method has some preparation and is relatively long it is does reasonably well on small lists and very well on very large lists.  Its chief advantages are:

- It computes the frequency count on the fly and only once per word.
- the only sorting is done on the word list itself.
- no additional computation is repeated within the comparator.

So  First build a comparator.

- First compare the values in the first location in the array (the `a` count).
- then append each possible location of the next count using `thenComparing`
- finally, reverse the entire comparator to sort in reverse order.

```
Comparator<int[]> comp = Comparator.comparing(a -> a[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
    final int g = i;
    comp = comp.thenComparing(a -> a[g]);
}
comp = comp.reversed();
```

Now define a `Function` to get the letter frequency count of each word. This function takes a word and returns an int array of 26 values for the count of letters `a-z` in each word.  The count is case-insensitive.

```
Function<String, int[]> frequency = (word) -> {
    int[] counts = new int[26];
    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
        counts[Character.toLowerCase(ch)
                - 'a']++;
    }
    return counts;
};
```

Now its time to sort.  Putting it all together:

- stream the words
- create an `Entry` for each word where the `key` is the word and `value` is the frequency count computed for that word.
- then sort on the `Entry#value` using the previously built comparator.
- and map to the key, and return in a list.

```
List<String> words = List.of("Banana", "Isle", "Best", "baha", "baby","bad", "animal", "zoo", "elephant");

List<String> result = words.stream().map(
        word -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, int[]>(
                word, frequency.apply(word)))
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(comp))
        .map(Entry::getKey).toList();

System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
[Banana, baha, animal, baby, bad, elephant, Best, Isle, zoo]
```